# Disadvantages of Euclidean metrics when applied to binary vectors

Tags: binary-data, metric

I have found an [excellent overview](http://www.iiisci.org/journal/CV$/sci/pdfs/GS315JG.pdf) of binary metrics as referred [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58706/distance-metrics-for-binary-vectors).

My question is: what is the serious disadvantage of the application of Euclidean metric to binary data?

I have a gut feeling that it is wrong, but I would appreciate deeper explanation.

Comment: IF the data are in high dimension (they usually are), you have the curse of dimensionality: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions. Was this your gut feeling?