# Best similarity measure for binary wine data

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data, similarities

I'm creating a dataset of wine grape varieties and their associated flavors/aromas.  Here's a schematic of the data:

```
            Flavor1       Flavor2       Flavor3       Flavor4    ...

   Grape1      1             1             1             0

   Grape2      0             0             0             1

   Grape3      0             0             1             0

   Grape4      1             1             1             1

   ...
```

1 = grape has the flavor

0 = grape doesn't have the flavor

I plan to plot histograms for each grape variety and do a visual check, but I imagine there's some similarity matrix I could construct for these data.  I'm not the most advanced statistics user, so something readily implementable in a statistical package would be great, if at all possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Best for what? There are dozens of measures for such data.

Comment: @ttnphns  I don't have the knowledge to answer that question unfortunately.  I was hoping that the structure of my dataset might suggest something, but maybe not.  Basically, I'm looking for something easily implementable and easily interpretable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try one of the following distance measures

- [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)
- [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

If you are on python, the following [package](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) gives you a list of algorithms to experiment with out of the box

Just check out the "Metrics intended for boolean-valued vector spaces"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643548/how-to-use-mahalanobis-distance-in-sklearn-distancemetrics) you can get a short recipe for doing so

This [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58706/distance-metrics-for-binary-vectors) might be a good further reading